# eagle library--updated footprint wont show in board

Tags: eaglecad

I initially created a part in an eagle library, but now I need to change the package layout. I have already put the initial part in an eagle schematic, so removing/re-inserting it is not an option. So anyway, I opened the library editor up and edited the part's package layout, and saved the library. I then went back to my schematic, went to the **library** dropdown **----->Update library**, and selected the library that I edited. I then created a board from the schematic(I didn't already have a board--I am not even done with the schematic. I just created the board to test if the library update worked.) Unfortunately, the package on the board remained the old one, not the edited version of the package layout. I then tried doing the same **library** dropdown **----->Update library** while inside the board editor, but still no luck.

How do I update the part so that the board uses the new package library? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Eagle? Usually I have to right click on the part and "Replace" it with the updated part in the library. Eagle files copy the data from the library into your project, so the library part isn't really linked in any way to your schematic after you add the part.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks so much! it worked! can you please add that as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eagle stores the symbol, footprint, and schematic information inside the project file itself. This means that once you insert a part, the part information is copied out of the library and placed in the .sch file. The link to the library is lost.

In order to update the part in the schematic/board, you need to right click on the part and select "Replace":

[image]

Then select the part again from the updated library. As long as the connections are the same, the new part will be replaced in the schematic/board with the updated part. If there are pin conflicts, it will notify you.